# Does ggsurvplot_combine() not support the calculation of p-values?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, p-value, survminer

I would like to plot the survival of a single group against the survival of the entire population in a single Kaplan-Meier plot.

Version 1:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(survminer)

df <- data.frame(Time     = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4),
                 Censored = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                 Group    = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'))

fit1 <- survfit(Surv(Time, Censored) ~ 1, data = df)
fit2 <- survfit(Surv(Time, Censored) ~ 1, data = subset(df, Group == 'B'))

ggsurvplot_combine(list('0' = fit1, 'B' = fit2), pval = TRUE)
```

The p-value is not displayed. Does ggsurvplot_combine() not support the calculation of p-values?

My current workaround is as follows. Version 2:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(survminer)

df <- data.frame(Time     = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4),
                 Censored = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                 Group    = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'))

df1 <- df %>% mutate(Strata = '0')
df2 <- df %>% filter(Group == 'B') %>% mutate(Strata = 'B')
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)

fit <- survfit(Surv(Time, Censored) ~ Strata, data = df3)

ggsurvplot(fit, pval = TRUE)
```

I would prefer using version 1, because it uses the dataset without the need to make copies of the data frame.

Comment: You need version 2 because both strata have to be in the same model to calculate a *P*-value in the first place. You could call `survminer::surv_pvalue` and add the annotation yourself, but that function requires a single fit object, as would any other logrank test short of re-implementing the combining logic of the separate curves yourself. I'm also not sure it's a sound idea to compare group B against a combination containing itself?

Comment: you shouldn't compare (with a p-value) a subset of the data to the whole population with it included because it violates the independence assumption, not all observations are independent. You can still make the Kaplan Meier without the p-value because it is just a characterization of the data

Comment: @Mike. That's a strong argument that I hadn't thought about. It's probably best to test the subgroup against the rest of the population.